# Why is there a scrollbar at the bottom

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I was experimenting with Zurb Foundation for a certain project, and for my page I used this.

```
 <div class="row text-center">
    <h3>Laurem Ipsom Dolor</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 small-offset-2 columns">
        <img src="some.svg"  class="thumbnail centered">
        <h3>Laurem Ipsom Dolor</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="small-4 end columns">
        <img src="another.svg" class="thumbnail centered">
        <h3>Laurem Ipsom Dolor</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/f7kb9x6n/

So why is there a scrollbar (why does it exceed page width) at the bottom for medium and small screen sizes (example jsfiddle window which is usually quarter of a screen)

centered class just does a margin:auto, but shouldn't be of concern here as I haven't even defined it in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't nest a `.row` inside another `.row`, direct childrens of `.row` should be `.column` (or `.columns`, whatever do you use), this markup should work for your case:

```
 <div class="row text-center">
     <div class="column">
          <h3>Laurem Ipsom Dolor</h3>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="small-4 small-offset-2 columns">
              <img src="some.svg"  class="thumbnail centered">
              <h3>Laurem Ipsom Dolor</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="small-4 end columns">
              <img src="another.svg" class="thumbnail centered">
              <h3>Laurem Ipsom Dolor</h3>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

To answer *why this happens*, is because negative margin the `.row` apply to compensate the column gutter (spacing between columns). Please don't edit the CSS rules for `.row .row`, you'll be messing the Foundation grid.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Zurb docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html) you have to nest the second `.row` inside a `.columns` like in [this fiddle forked](https://jsfiddle.net/fxz9xuc0/)

Answer (score 0):

It is from your external css file.

Reason:

```
  .row .row {
     margin-left: -.625rem;
     margin-right: -.625rem;
     max-width: none;
   }
```

Remove margin right and try.

Comment: Is this normal css behaviour for zurb foundation?

We are unable to nest 2 row classes without breaking it?

Comment: @The0bserver you can, but `.row` direct children should be `.column`, if you follow that rule, you can do any nesting you want to

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-center {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Use this. It's working